# SSIS Sporadic Error When Reading Large Excel Files. Unexpected Termination

Tags: excel, ssis, termination, ms-jet-ace

We have an SSIS process which consumes data from Excel files using the oledb excel connectors.  The code runs reliably successfully consuming the files and writing them to staging in our DB.

However there is a sporadic failure which has occurred twice in the last 6 months.
The process simply stops running, and the Integration Services Catalog shows the Status `Unexpected Termination`. There is no error message reported so we aren't able to trouble shoot further.

If I simply rerun the process it works fine and it will continue to work for many months.

The process usually loops through and consumes about 60 or 70 excel files, varying in size,
there are usually about 20 or so large files of 40 to 70 MB.
(Ideally we should not be dealing with excel files that big, but that is what the source provider gives us. I would prefer CSV's or something else for sure. )

The connection string being used :
`Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=C:\bla\blabla\sourcefile.xlsx;Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;MAXSCANROWS=104567";`

The error msg from windows:

> Faulting application name: ISServerExec.exe, version: 14.0.3436.1,
> time stamp: 0x6234eb8a Faulting module name: mso99Lwin32client.dll,
> version: 16.0.5239.1001, time stamp: 0x617113af Exception code:
> 0xc000041d Fault offset: 0x0000000000181dea Faulting process id: 0xad0
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d87c5510d88ed0 Faulting
> application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
> Server\140\DTS\Binn\ISServerExec.exe Faulting module path: C:\Program
> Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office16\mso99Lwin32client.dll
> Report Id: bdd23f34-1a78-445c-b134-96935ab43ed0 Faulting package full
> name: Faulting package-relative application ID:

The process normally works. But sporadically fails with the above error logged in the windows event log.

I have searched and not found anything relevant. Any ideas or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Aamer

Comment: I am making a guess from this `mso99Lwin32client.dll` -- it looks like you might be running 32 bit office, in which case this might be a memory error.  If this is true, it would be worth exploring replacing it with 64 bit.

Comment: I will bring that up with our infra guys to follow up further. thanks for that pointer.